# Take so long to boot VM via softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying to boot VM on IBM cloud (softlayer) via softlayer API, I'm using softlayer python client(5.4.4), it can work actually with my username and api key, but it took so long to boot a VM via API(normally 20~30 minutes), especially compare to operation with web GUI(5~10 minutes).

it seems that softlayer accepted the request of booting VM, but transcation will not start immediately(in my case, after 20 minutes, then transaction started).

I'm wondering if that's because softlayer put lower priority for API request? by the way, I was trying to boot VM on hkg02 and fra02, the problem is same.

So how can I accelerate this process when I use the API call?

Answer (score 0):

Brian, currently the portal GUI use Api requests in the background, so it shouldn`t be any different, or like you mentioned: the UI be better or faster than the API.

In case you continue having this behavior on specific servers/datacenters, then you could submit a ticket so the proper department could take a look on them, as it doesn`t seem an Api issue for what was clarified previously.